# Recalculate taxes on programatically created invoice in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, rpc, odoo-12

In odoo I have created an invoice with correct invoice line items ( including tax ). I am using a node module for this which calls the /web/dataset/call_kw endpoint in odoo.

My problem is, that the tax on the invoice is not updated after adding the line items. It remains 0. Can I force the recalculation of the invoice or must I calculate the total tax and set it on the invoice programatically?

I have tried to call the method `button_reset_taxes()` on the `account.invoice` object via the web api, but failed.

Error:

> account.invoice has no attribute button_reset_taxes.

Comment: How do you call button_reset_taxes?

Comment: Well, that was my question too, but I solved the problem differently. I am manually setting the tax amount on the invoice, as it is known to me.